# java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlinx.coroutines.CompletableDeferredImpl cannot be cast to java.util.List?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, classcastexception, kotlin-coroutines

I am developing a new android app but I am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlinx.coroutines.CompletableDeferredImpl cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.viewmodel.MainViewModel$loadNews$1.invokeSuspend(MainViewModel.kt:42)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
```

in my MainViewModel.kt

below my MainViewModel.kt

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class MainViewModel(val newsRepository: NewsRepository) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
    // Coroutine's background job
    val job = Job()
    // Define default thread for Coroutine as Main and add job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job

    val showLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val sportList = MutableLiveData <List<Article>>()
    val showError = SingleLiveEvent<String>()

    fun loadNews() {
        // Show progressBar during the operation on the MAIN (default) thread
        showLoading.value = true
        // launch the Coroutine
        launch {
            // Switching from MAIN to IO thread for API operation
            // Update our data list with the new one from API
            val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                newsRepository?.getNewsList()
            }
            // Hide progressBar once the operation is done on the MAIN (default) thread
            showLoading.value = false
            when (result) {

                is UseCaseResult.Success<*> -> {
                    sportList.value = result.data as List<Article>
                }
                is Error -> showError.value = result.message
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        // Clear our job when the linked activity is destroyed to avoid memory leaks
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

below Article.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = "news_table")
data class Article(@ColumnInfo(name = "author")val author: String,
                   val content: String,
                   val description: String,
                   val publishedAt: String,
                   val source: Source,
                   val title: String,
                   val url: String,
                   val urlToImage: String
)
```

below SportNewsResponse.kt

data class SportNewsResponse(
    val articles: List,
    val status: String,
    val totalResults: Int
)

below UseCaseResult.kt

```
sealed class UseCaseResult<out T : Any>() {
    class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : UseCaseResult<T>()
    class Error(val exception: Throwable) : UseCaseResult<Nothing>()
}
```

below NewsRepository.kt where I have implemented UserCaseResult

```
interface NewsRepository {
    // Suspend is used to await 
    suspend fun getNewsList(): UseCaseResult<List<Article>>
}


@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class NewsRepositoryImpl(private val sportsNewsApi: SportNewsInterface) : NewsRepository {
    override suspend fun getNewsList(): UseCaseResult<List<Article>> {

        return try {
            val result = sportsNewsApi.getNewsAsync()
            UseCaseResult.Success(result) as UseCaseResult<List<Article>>
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            UseCaseResult.Error(ex)
        }
    }
}
```

below my SportNewsInteface.kt

```
interface SportNewsInterface {

    @GET("v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
     fun getNewsAsync(): Deferred<SportNewsResponse>

    @GET("/v2/top-headlines?sources=espn&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
    fun getEspn(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>

    @GET("/v2/top-headlines?sources=football-italia&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
    fun getFootballItalia(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>

    @GET("/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-sport&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
    fun getBBCSport(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>
```

below my Response from server

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 38,
    "articles": [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "cnbc",
                "name": "CNBC"
            },
            "author": "Holly Ellyatt",
            "title": "Russia is now not the only pressing issue that NATO has to deal with - CNBC",
            "description": "Heads of state and government are meeting in the U.K. this week for the 70th anniversary of the military alliance NATO.",
            "url": "https://www.cnbc.com/2019/12/02/nato-summit-alliance-has-more-pressing-issues-than-russia-now.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/106272467-1575218599700gettyimages-997112494.jpeg?v=1575218712",
            "publishedAt": "2019-12-02T07:39:00Z",
            "content": "US president Donald Trump is seen during his press conference at the 2018 NATO Summit in Brussels, Belgium on July 12, 2018.\r\nAs heads of state and government meet in the U.K. this week for the 70th anniversary of the military alliance NATO, discussions are l… [+8623 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Chron.com"
            },
            "author": "Aaron Wilson",
            "title": "Bill O'Brien gets game ball from Deshaun Watson after Texans' win over Patriots - Chron",
            "description": "In an emotional moment, Texans coach Bill O'Brien was presented with the game ball by quarterback Deshaun Watson following a pivotal win over the New England Patriots.",
            "url": "https://www.chron.com/sports/texans/article/Bill-O-Brien-Deshaun-Watson-Texans-Patriots-14874678.php",
            "urlToImage": "https://s.hdnux.com/photos/01/07/23/50/18692664/3/rawImage.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2019-12-02T06:16:00Z",
            "content": "<ul><li>Houston Texans head coach Bill O'Brien on the sidelines during the fourth quarter of an NFL game against the New England Patriots at NRG Stadium Sunday, Dec. 1, 2019, in Houston.\r\nHouston Texans head coach Bill O'Brien on the sidelines during the four… [+1583 chars]"


        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is the output of: `result.data.await()::class` ?

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect:

```
val result = sportsNewsApi.getNewsAsync()
```

Correct:

```
val result = sportsNewsApi.getNewsAsync().await()
```

Comment: exception it is still the same

Comment: I very much doubt that. Maybe you're still casting to a wrong type, but the object you're trying to cast has changed. You should share your new stack trace.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.internet.SportNewsResponse cannot be cast to java.util.List
 at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.viewmodel.MainViewModel$loadNews$1.invokeSuspend(MainViewModel.kt:43)
 at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)

Comment: I am getting above exception I did not understand what I am making wrong

Comment: Well you see, now you're getting a `SportNewsResponse` but pretending it's a `List`. Now call a method that gets the list of articles. Maybe `result.getArticles()`.

Comment: where exactly I have to implement can you explain in coding sample

Answer (score 0):

```
  val result = sportsNewsApi.getNewsAsync()
  UseCaseResult.Success(result) as UseCaseResult<List<Article>>
```

That cast is very suspicious since it should work even without it. That means your cast is invalid, causing the error you're seeing.

Comment: I dont understand what you exactly mean

Comment: `getNewsAsync()` doesn't return an `List<Article>`, so that code is incorrect. A correct implementation cannot be given without specifying what `getNewsAsync()` actually returns.

Comment: it returns SportNewsResponse ending points I will add to code now

Comment: I have added all necessary files please check it

Comment: what do you think main problem

Comment: Try to explain to yourself HOW `UseCaseResult<List<Article>>` is the result by looking at the types returned by the functions, then work backwards because I can guarantee it does not make sense.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I have changed data type to UseCaseResult<List<SportNewsResponse>> it is the still the same what is your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

So you already made some changes
Now  getNewsAsync must return UseCaseResult not a list of it, since that's what The endpoint is returning.
Then you can get the articles inside this object

Comment: @juliribeiro if I change I am getting error in TopHeadlinesFragment.kt thats logic I did not understand

Answer (score 0):

in `NewsRepository`
in this 2 lines

```
 val result = sportsNewsApi.getNewsAsync()
 UseCaseResult.Success(result) as UseCaseResult<List<Article>>
```

you are trying to cast `result` to `UseCaseResult<List<Article>>`
, but in `SportNewsInterface` the `getNewsAsync()` fun returns `Deferred<SportNewsResponse>` thus you must cast it to `UseCaseResult<Deferred<SportNewsResponse>>` like this.

```
UseCaseResult.Success(result) as UseCaseResult<Deferred<SportNewsResponse>>
```

or if you want to fetch the value use `.await()` on `getNewsAsync()` like this

```
val result = sportsNewsApi.getNewsAsync().await()
 UseCaseResult.Success(result) as UseCaseResult<SportNewsResponse>
```

don't forget now you should cast result to `UseCaseResult<SportNewsResponse>` and remove `Deferred`

Comment: C:\Users\Edgar\Desktop\SportNews\app\src\main\java\yodgorbek\komilov\musobaqayangiliklari\repository\NewsRepository.kt: (22, 60): Unresolved reference: SportNewsResponse I am getting error below what is your suggestion

Comment: I have tried your first approach as well it is giving this error Unresolved reference: Deferred

Comment: Have you added dependencies to you project? `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2"`